# CraftCMS 2 -> 3 Migration error: syntax error, unexpected 'const' (T_CONST), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: error, plugin-freeform, solspace, freeform

I've successfully upgraded a Craft 2 install to Craft 3 on my local machine, but now that I've moved everything to production, I'm getting this error anytime I try to load a template that uses Freeform or edit an entry that uses the Freeform Matrix field, or when I try to remove the Freeform Matrix field from use.

```
ParseError: syntax error, unexpected 'const' (T_CONST), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/symfony/property-access/PropertyAccessor.php:36
Stack trace:
#0 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(322): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/nfs/c12/h02/mn...')
#1 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Symfony\\Compone...')
#2 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/symfony/property-access/PropertyAccessorBuilder.php(131): spl_autoload_call('Symfony\\Compone...')
#3 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/symfony/property-access/PropertyAccess.php(28): Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessorBuilder->getPropertyAccessor()
#4 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/solspace/craft3-freeform/src/Library/Composer/Components/AbstractField.php(82): Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor()
#5 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/solspace/craft3-freeform/src/Library/Factories/ComposerFieldFactory.php(75): Solspace\Freeform\Library\Composer\Components\AbstractField::createFromProperties(Object(Solspace\Freeform\Library\Composer\Components\Form), Object(Solspace\Freeform\Library\Composer\Components\Properties\FieldProperties), Object(Solspace\Freeform\Library\Session\FormValueContext), 0)
#6 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/solspace/craft3-freeform/src/Library/Composer/Components/Layout.php(364): Solspace\Freeform\Library\Factories\ComposerFieldFactory::createFromProperties(Object(Solspace\Freeform\Library\Composer\Components\Form), Object(Solspace\Freeform\Library\Composer\Components\Properties\FieldProperties), Object(Solspace\Freeform\Library\Session\FormValueContext), 0)
#7 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/solspace/craft3-freeform/src/Library/Composer/Components/Layout.php(101): Solspace\Freeform\Library\Composer\Components\Layout->buildLayout(Object(Solspace\Freeform\Library\Session\FormValueContext))
#8 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/solspace/craft3-freeform/src/Library/Composer/Components/Form.php(179): Solspace\Freeform\Library\Composer\Components\Layout->__construct(Object(Solspace\Freeform\Library\Composer\Components\Form), Array, Object(Solspace\Freeform\Library\Composer\Components\Properties), Object(Solspace\Freeform\Library\Session\FormValueContext), Object(Solspace\Freeform\Library\Translations\CraftTranslator))
#9 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/solspace/craft3-freeform/src/Library/Composer/Composer.php(226): Solspace\Freeform\Library\Composer\Components\Form->__construct(Object(Solspace\Freeform\Library\Composer\Components\Properties), Object(Solspace\Freeform\Library\Composer\Attributes\FormAttributes), Array, Object(Solspace\Freeform\Services\FormsService), Object(Solspace\Freeform\Services\FieldsService), Object(Solspace\Freeform\Services\SubmissionsService), Object(Solspace\Freeform\Services\SpamSubmissionsService), Object(Solspace\Freeform\Services\FilesService), Object(Solspace\Freeform\Library\Translations\CraftTranslator), Object(Monolog\Logger))
#10 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/solspace/craft3-freeform/src/Library/Composer/Composer.php(112): Solspace\Freeform\Library\Composer\Composer->validateComposerData(Object(Solspace\Freeform\Library\Composer\Attributes\FormAttributes))
#11 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/solspace/craft3-freeform/src/Models/FormModel.php(141): Solspace\Freeform\Library\Composer\Composer->__construct(Array, Object(Solspace\Freeform\Library\Composer\Attributes\FormAttributes), Object(Solspace\Freeform\Services\FormsService), Object(Solspace\Freeform\Services\FieldsService), Object(Solspace\Freeform\Services\SubmissionsService), Object(Solspace\Freeform\Services\SpamSubmissionsService), Object(Solspace\Freeform\Services\FilesService), Object(Solspace\Freeform\Services\StatusesService), Object(Solspace\Freeform\Library\Translations\CraftTranslator), Object(Monolog\Logger))
#12 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/solspace/craft3-freeform/src/Models/FormModel.php(181): Solspace\Freeform\Models\FormModel->getComposer()
#13 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/solspace/craft3-freeform/src/Variables/FreeformVariable.php(39): Solspace\Freeform\Models\FormModel->getForm()
#14 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php(1619): Solspace\Freeform\Variables\FreeformVariable->form('contact')
#15 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/helpers/Template.php(73): twig_get_attribute(Object(craft\web\twig\Environment), Object(Twig_Source), Object(Solspace\Freeform\Variables\FreeformVariable), 'form', Array, 'method', false, false)
#16 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/49/490c1e38c73774194ec4db7b0d434edd73b90ada852ba19a47d7151deaf8baae.php(1134): craft\helpers\Template::attribute(Object(craft\web\twig\Environment), Object(Twig_Source), Object(Solspace\Freeform\Variables\FreeformVariable), 'form', Array, 'method')
#17 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(189): __TwigTemplate_df6084533b45dbb97216b53f70d72500723f0c627d73d735f02e06ac485c51df_1371066880->block_content(Array, Array)
#18 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/e1/e18892d07e96f54281b257243b47df5c3c472532bb04f3dcd598cc90f7caf331.php(33): Twig_Template->displayBlock('content', Array, Array)
#19 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(390): __TwigTemplate_a9075adcd269d2a009f2e9ea0a663da5fb05a154b25ba8bfe126edf0b84781bf->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#20 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/Template.php(49): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#21 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(367): craft\web\twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#22 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/Template.php(31): Twig_Template->display(Array, Array)
#23 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/49/490c1e38c73774194ec4db7b0d434edd73b90ada852ba19a47d7151deaf8baae.php(435): craft\web\twig\Template->display(Array, Array)
#24 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(390): __TwigTemplate_df6084533b45dbb97216b53f70d72500723f0c627d73d735f02e06ac485c51df_1371066880->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#25 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/Template.php(49): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#26 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(367): craft\web\twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#27 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/Template.php(31): Twig_Template->display(Array, Array)
#28 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/49/490c1e38c73774194ec4db7b0d434edd73b90ada852ba19a47d7151deaf8baae.php(91): craft\web\twig\Template->display(Array)
#29 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(390): __TwigTemplate_df6084533b45dbb97216b53f70d72500723f0c627d73d735f02e06ac485c51df->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#30 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/Template.php(49): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#31 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(367): craft\web\twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#32 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/Template.php(31): Twig_Template->display(Array, Array)
#33 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/55/5508cdc0a50b370b23f6ec0ba3962a8c8153a034e0b199e7615d133dde1089c9.php(41): craft\web\twig\Template->display(Array)
#34 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(189): __TwigTemplate_b21fc72ed6773279e32ba5c448920e81587c43b17bf5d251d680273efee40c38->block_content(Array, Array)
#35 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/50/50ddd0fb8796360ec27783bd66594cb5d81bb2d0d7c6c3aa7efd96a7d6c6f4b3.php(123): Twig_Template->displayBlock('content', Array, Array)
#36 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(390): __TwigTemplate_2e2b57df12e19bc3a90c2a8d5cecd81a1a85b4424d1a3677d92914c0df6b3f10->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#37 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/Template.php(49): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#38 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(367): craft\web\twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#39 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/Template.php(31): Twig_Template->display(Array, Array)
#40 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/55/5508cdc0a50b370b23f6ec0ba3962a8c8153a034e0b199e7615d133dde1089c9.php(31): craft\web\twig\Template->display(Array, Array)
#41 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(390): __TwigTemplate_b21fc72ed6773279e32ba5c448920e81587c43b17bf5d251d680273efee40c38->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#42 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/Template.php(49): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#43 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(367): craft\web\twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#44 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/Template.php(31): Twig_Template->display(Array, Array)
#45 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(375): craft\web\twig\Template->display(Array)
#46 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(289): Twig_Template->render(Array)
#47 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/View.php(331): Twig_Environment->render('index', Array)
#48 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/View.php(378): craft\web\View->renderTemplate('index', Array)
#49 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Controller.php(156): craft\web\View->renderPageTemplate('index', Array)
#50 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/controllers/TemplatesController.php(78): craft\web\Controller->renderTemplate('index', Array)
#51 [internal function]: craft\controllers\TemplatesController->actionRender('index', Array)
#52 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#53 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(157): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#54 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Controller.php(104): yii\base\Controller->runAction('render', Array)
#55 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(528): craft\web\Controller->runAction('render', Array)
#56 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(282): yii\base\Module->runAction('templates/rende...', Array)
#57 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(103): craft\web\Application->runAction('templates/rende...', Array)
#58 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(271): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#59 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): craft\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#60 /nfs/c12/h02/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/domain.com/html/index.php(21): yii\base\Application->run()
#61 {main}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error means that your Craft installation is choking on one of Craft's Composer dependencies that is using newer PHP 7.1 syntax and your current box is using PHP 7.0.x.

Usually when that happens, someone did a Composer install/update locally using a newer version of PHP than what you have on then box you're getting the error on, then deployed the composer.json, composer.lock and vendor folder up using the latest and greatest dependencies Composer thinks you can use.

In cases like this, it's usually better to add something like this to your composer.json file https://github.com/pixelandtonic/craftnet/blob/develop/composer.json#L37-L41

Make sure you set that to the "lowest common PHP denominator" across all of your environments. That way, Composer will never try to bring in a dependency that's greater than any environment can support.

Comment: Thanks @brad-bell — this was exactly it. I don't know if there's an easier way to correct it, but I essentially backed up the DB/assets and burned everything to the ground and reinstalled being careful to keep php versions set in composer.json. Thanks!